# Export text file with custom extension Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, export

For a project working with Prodigy, I want to have a .jsonl file, in which each line is a json file.

To do so, I have the following code:

```
df['json'] = df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True).splitlines()

jsonl = ""

for js in df['json']:
    jsonl += js + '\n'
```

How can I export this text to the following name/directory:

```
DIRECTORY/texts.jsonl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved the hard part. You can write `jsonl` directly to a file:

```
with open("DIRECTORY/texts.jsonl", "w") as f:
    f.write(jsonl)
```